# Mongodb - Connection Pool size not reflecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongodb has default connection poll size eq 5 .

I have a problem with connection pool size always equal 1 if I connect to mongodb by mongodb client and equal 2 if I connect to mongodb by mongoose

regarding to mongoose if I set poolSize=1 the connection poolSize will be one, if I tried to make it higher than two the poolSize will be two only

I also set maxPoolSize for mongoose and mongodb client, not reflecting !!

I am checking connection pool size from mongodb server by command 
 "`db.serverStatus().connections`"

However If I logged form client (`connections.length`) it's always equal 1 , for mongoose and mongodb client as well

I want to know if there is configuration for mongodb server or the operating system " Debian 9 " to update max pool size

I have tried many ways to set poolSize ( By add it as query param or options object )

Mongodb performance is too bad ->

I was testing express http server by jmeter by sending request from one thread infinite loop the throughput was 12000 + 
the response was static hello world text

after adding mongoose and send response ( find all records in table has only 5 records ) the throughput is 600+ only

So I would like to know how to maximize connection pool and hacks to enhance mongoose performance

Ps: I have changed  ulimit open files  to be 64000

Mongoose connection code :

```
mongoose.connect(dbUrl , {  useNewUrlParser: true  , 
                        autoReconnect:true ,
                        poolSize: 100,
                        reconnectInterval: 1000,
                        reconnectTries: 30
                    });
var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.once('open', function() {
  console.log(mongoose.connections.length);
});
```

Mongodb Client code :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, {
useNewUrlParser: true , 
  poolSize: 1000
  }, function(err, client) {

!err ? console.log('') :console.log(client);
});
```

Comment: Me too, I am facing this issue, poolSize option is not being taken by MongoDB into consideration.

Comment: I have the same issue too!